# Getting Error when try to connect real device in IOS using Appium

Tags: ios, selenium-webdriver, appium

I am trying to automate ios mobile application. I have configure all classpath , installed appium , eclipse and have done everything. But now when I run my program , I am getting error :

```
   A new session could not be created. (Original error: Could not initialize        
ideviceinstaller; make sure it is installed and works on your system)(WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 1.34 seconds
Build info: version: '2.46.0', revision: '87c69e2', time: '2015-06-04    16:16:47'
    System info: host: 'www.example.com', ip: 'xxx.xxx.x.xxx',     os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.10.4', java.version: '1.8.0_45'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver
```

---

My code is :

```
File path = new File("/Users/test/Desktop/myapp.ipa");



// Setting capabilities
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();


//capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, ""); 
capabilities.setCapability("device", "iPhone 6+");
capabilities.setCapability("udid", "xxxxxxx");


capabilities.setCapability("deviceName","iPhone 6+");
capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "8.4.1");
capabilities.setCapability("app", "settings");

driver = new IOSDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub/"), capabilities)
```

Note : I have tried all these - https://goo.gl/rf4KJV  solutions but no luck.

Comment: https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/4584 This might be useful

Comment: Make sure appium server is running before you run your test.

Comment: @Gaurav - Yes I verified that...

Answer (score 0):

Please install **ideviceinstaller properly and set the path for ideviceinstaller**
Use the following command to install ideviceinstaller brew install --HEAD ideviceinstaller

> $ brew install --HEAD ideviceinstaller

if ideviceinstaller is already install. then unlink it and link it back using following commands

> $ brew unlink ideviceinstaller
>
> $ brew link ideviceinstaller

Comment: And after installation try the command **`ideviceinstaller -l`**